# No error for negative-size array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, stdarray

Why don't I get an error trying to create a negative-size array?

```
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, -1> arr;
}
```

With `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC` I get no error. Is this intended behavior?

Comment: Which compiler you are using? I used gcc 5.3.1 and i got error 'size of variable ‘arr’ is too large'

Answer (score 20):

No it's not legal. There's nothing about the specification of `std::array` that explicitly prevents this, but it's illegal because of narrowing conversions.

§14.3.2/5:

> For a non-type template-parameter of integral or enumeration type, conversions 
>   permitted in a converted constant expression (5.19) are applied.

§5.19/3:

> A converted constant expression of type T is a literal constant expression, 
>   implicitly converted to type T, where the implicit conversion (if any) is 
>   permitted in a literal constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence
>   contains only user-defined conversions, lvalue-to-rvalue conversions (4.1), 
>   integral promotions (4.5), and integral conversions (4.7) other than narrowing 
>   conversions (8.5.4)

The only way to get GCC to complain is to enable `-Wsign-conversion`. This is a [known bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57891) and they haven't made any movement to fix it.

In Clang you get the expected error message:

```
error: non-type template argument evaluates to -1, which cannot be 
narrowed to type 'std::size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wc++11-narrowing]
    std::array<int, -1> arr;
```

Comment: Historical note: in published C++11 it was implementation-defined whether this was a narrowing conversion, but this was fixed by DR 1449 to always be narrowing

Answer (score 8):

Type of `std::array` is:

```
template< 
    class T, 
    std::size_t N 
> struct array;
```

When you initialize second template parameter with `-1`, it is implicitly converted to a very large value as `std::size_t` is `unsigned` (which is illegal in C++ as pointed by [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37290298/no-error-for-negative-size-array/37290467#37290467) and it should be diagnosed).

Another possibility is that your `arr` is optimized out. You can confirm this by adding `-fdump-tree-optimized` flag to gcc command line.

If you ensure `arr` is not optimized out, I hope you should get the [following warning](http://ideone.com/olnlYo):

```
prog.cpp:5:25: error: size of variable 'arr' is too large
     std::array<int, -1> arr;
```

Comment: Doesn't optimization happen after such warning checks?

Comment: @BartoszKP I used `gcc --std=c++11 -O2 -fdump-tree-optimized arr_que.cpp` and confirmed that code is optimized to just `return 0;` as you might expect. I am not sure whether template parameter misuse must be diagnosed.